# Reading TD1 MRZ from image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I am delevoping a program that should detect the MRZ(TD1) text and return it as a string from the back of emirates card. I have done the same for passports(TD3) using Python and 'mrz_reader' package that uses tesseract to convert image to text and its working perfect. But i tried the same for emirates card and results wasn't even close to actual one. I have tried couple of solutions like using different libraries to detect mrz applying some image healing via opencv before tesseract string detection but either mrz area is not getting detected or the result string is not correct at all.

[image]

Result for top emirates id: J784197619049089LSLE<<<<<<<<<<<6<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

I have checked the internet for a solution but I couldn't find anything that suits for this case. How can I achieve an accurate result for emirates card mrz scanning ?

Answer (score 0):

You should Use Paddle OCR for extraction it works great, I have tested the card image you shared, the results are good in terms of MRZ. I have only used the English models along with English dictionary. You can train the model too according to your use case and there is support of Arabic language too. For more info you can refer to  https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR

Result:
[Paddle OCR Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYDOw.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).